# how to use jq to get the gap value between array

Tags: arrays, json, jq

**I had the following json array:**

```json
{
  "metric": {
    "instance": "100.120.207.215:8081",
    "job": "job1",
    "error_code": "500"
  },
  "values": [
    [
      1665129206,
      "128"
    ],
    [
      1665129236,
      "129"
    ],
    [
      1665129266,
      "130"
    ],
    [
      1665129296,
      "135"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to get the difference between each array, looks like

```
1665129236,1
1665129266,1
1665129296,5
```

Please help on it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The second gap should be a "1", shouldn't it?  See also the output shown in pmf's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the arrays fit your memory, you can make two copies, shift them one apart to each other, transpose and subtract:

```bash
.values | [.[:-1], .[1:]] | transpose[]
| "\(.[1][0]),\(map(.[1] | tonumber) | .[1]-.[0])"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/52urnHqq2HO)

Alternatively, you can use either `foreach` or `while` to iterate over a window of two adjacent items:

```bash
.values | foreach .[1:][] as $v ([null, .[0]]; .[1:] + [$v];
  "\(.[1][0]),\(map(.[1] | tonumber) | .[1]-.[0])"
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DixOP5eVlVv)

```bash
.values | while(has(1); .[1:])[:2]
| "\(.[1][0]),\(map(.[1] | tonumber) | .[1]-.[0])"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/m4JEIqYW1EI)

Output:

```bash
1665129236,1
1665129266,1
1665129296,5
```

Comment: Thanks pmf's great answer. Is it possible to filter the second colume with value>3?

Comment: @walkaround2002 Keeping the same output format, you can add any `select` expression after `.[1]-.[0]` to filter, e.g. `"\(.[1][0]),\(map(.[1] | tonumber) | .[1]-.[0] | select(. > 3))"` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nCSceAqOByQ). For the sake of operability, however, I'd suggest to first collect the values into an array instead (e.g. `[.[1][0],(map(.[1] | tonumber) | .[1]-.[0])]` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1muy6beYWzP)), which then makes any further processing easier and more readable, e.g. `select(.[1] > 3)` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AItalTadLaV)

Answer (score 0):

Building on [pmf's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74012321/112968):

```
.values[][1] |= tonumber
| [.values[1:], .values[:-1]]
| transpose[]
| [
  first[0],
  (map(last) | first-last)
]
| join(",")
```

Since all your values are numbers, the final `join` filter could be replaced with `@csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a generic `derivative` function that has already been used elsewhere on SO:

```
# Input: an array
# `delta` should be a non-negative integer, typically 1;
# p is the jq path expression to the quantity within an item, e.g. `.`
def derivative(delta; p):
  . as $in
  | [ range(delta; length) as $i
      | .[$i]
      | (p = ($in[$i] | p) - ($in[$i - delta] | p)) ];

.values |=
  (map(.[1] |= tonumber)
   | derivative( 1; .[1]))
```